# How to validate the google video code?

Tags: php, api

In my project, users insert a Google Video code into a textbox - I'd like to certify that the video being referenced does indeed exist. I'm presently using the YouTube API to do something similar with YouTube references, but I'm not sure what would be the best method with Google Video. Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you request the URL and see if it 404s or not?

```
function googleVideoExist($id) {
    // Validate id however you need to
    $id = (int) $id;

    $headers = get_headers('http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=' . $id, TRUE);

    // get_headers() follows Location: headers,
    // and they are all sent back in sequential order
    foreach(array_reverse($headers) as $header => $value) {
        if (strstr($value, '200')) {
          return TRUE;
       }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

URL above is a guide only - adapt it to suit. Also, you can use cURL if you are more comfortable with that.

Comment: I have to check the provided google video code is existed or not?

Comment: @Mayilarun Just my guess. Do they provide an API? If they do, that will probably be better. This will fail if the site is down for other reasons. Of course, you could check *not* for 404, but that may also be inaccurate.